# Problema com recuperar o retorno de um Promisse

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Antes eu estava com um problema que quando dava algum erro no na execução da query o servidor parava e era preciso reiniciar para voltar a funcionar, então dando uma pesquisada achei como resolver o problema tratando os erros com os metodos then e cacth.

Mas antes de usar o then e cacth, no meu model quando não avia erro ele retornava para o controller normalmente o id do item inserido no banco de dados.

O código do Model antes de usar then e cacth:

```
const db = require('../database/connection');
module.exports = {
    create: async ({ title, description, banner, vacancies, type }) => {

    return new Promise((resolver, reject) => {
        db.query('INSERT INTO events (`title`, `description`,  `banner`, `vacancies`, `type`) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?)',
            [title, description, banner, vacancies, type],
            (error, results) => {
                if (error) { reject(error); return; }
                resolver(results.insertId);
            }
        )
    }); 
}
```

}

Depois de usar o then e cacth o servidor se comportou como esperado quando ocorria algum erro, mostrando o erro mas não parava de funcionar, so que surgiu o problema de que no meu controller ao chamar a função de inserção *let event = await Event.create(values);* na minha variável event deveria receber o id do item inserido, so que ele esta sendo executada antes de terminar o processo de inserção.

Codigo do Model com o uso do then e cacth:

```
const db = require('../database/connection');
module.exports = {
create:async ({ title, description, banner, vacancies, type }) => {

    var res =  new Promise((resolver, reject) => {
        db.query('INSERT INTO events (`title`, `description`,  `banner`, `vacancies`, `type`) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?)',
            [title, description, banner, vacancies, type],
            (error, results) => {

                if (error) { reject(error); } 
                resolver(results);
            }
        )
    });

    res.then(insertId => {
        console.log(insertId, 'event');
        return(insertId);
        
    }).catch(rejectValeu => {
        console.log({rejectValeu});
        return;
    });

}
```

}

código do controller:

```
const Event = require('../models/Event');
```

module.exports = {
Create: async (req, res) => {

```
    let json = { error: {}, result: {}, status: {} };

    let { title, description, banner, vacancies, type } = req.body;

    let values = {
        title: title,
        description: description,
        banner: banner,
        vacancies: vacancies,
        type: type
    }

    let event = await Event.create(values);
    console.log(event, `controller`);

    if (event) {
        json.result = {
            id: event
        }
    }
    
    res.json(json);
 }}
```

Me falaram para usar try/catch no model, mas não tive sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente :

```
create:async ({ title, description, banner, vacancies, type }) => {
 
 var insert = () => {
        var res =  new Promise((resolver, reject) => {
    db.query('INSERT INTO events (`title`, `description`,  `banner`, `vacancies`, `type`) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?)',
        [title, description, banner, vacancies, type],
        (error, results) => {

            if (error) { reject(error); } 
            resolver(results);
        }
    )
});
return res;
};

try{
   var insertId = await insert();
   return(insertId);
}
catch(e)
{
      console.log({rejectValeu});
    return;
} }
```

Comment: Eu tinha colocado para retornar minha Promisse direto: return new Promisse (...); e no meu controller eu utilizei o then/catch desta forma: var event = await Event.create(values).then(insertId => {
            return(insertId);
        }).catch(rejectValeu => {
            console.log({rejectValeu});
            return;
        });
e deu certo, mas vou testar da forma que falou, obrigado.